# C# async await with dataflow BlockBuffer<T>

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, tpl-dataflow

I have a Winform application that needs to manage several state machines concurrently. Each state machine may have a socket, serial port or other external connection.

Here is my state machine shell implemented using async/await and dataflow BlockBuffer as a message queue.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class StateMachineMessage
{
    private static int id = 1;
    public int Id { get; } = 0;
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Text { get; }
    public BufferBlock<StateMachineMessage> Queue { get; set; }

    public StateMachineMessage(string name, string text)
    {
        Id = Interlocked.Increment(ref id);
        Name = name;
        Text = text;
        Queue = null;
    }

    public StateMachineMessage(string name, string text, BufferBlock<StateMachineMessage> queue)
    {
        Id = Interlocked.Increment(ref id);
        Name = name;
        Text = text;
        Queue = queue;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "(" + Id + ":" + Name + ":" + Text + ")";
    }
}

public class StateMachine
{
    private int State { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    RichTextBox TextBox { get; }
    BufferBlock<StateMachineMessage> Queue { get; }

    public StateMachine(string name, BufferBlock<StateMachineMessage> queue, RichTextBox textBox)
    {
        Name = name;
        Queue = queue;
        TextBox = textBox;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
        while (await Queue.OutputAvailableAsync())
        {
            var request = await Queue.ReceiveAsync();

            TextBox.AppendText(string.Format("{0}: {1}: {2}\n",
                               Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                               Name, request));

            if (request.Queue != null)
            {
                var response = new StateMachineMessage("RESPONSE", "Good Morning!");

                TextBox.AppendText(string.Format("{0}: {1}: {2}\n",
                              Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                              Name, response));

                await request.Queue.SendAsync(response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main form creates the dataflow block buffers and state machines on initialization.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace DataflowThread
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Enables the user interface to signal cancellation.
        CancellationTokenSource cancellationSource;

        // The worker state machine and dataflow node
        StateMachine workerMachine;
        BufferBlock<StateMachineMessage> workQueue;

        // The main thread state machine
        StateMachine mainMachine;
        BufferBlock<StateMachineMessage> mainQueue;


        // Enables progress bar actions to run on the UI thread.
        TaskScheduler uiTaskScheduler;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeDataflow();
            StartStateMachines();
        }

        public void InitializeDataflow()
        {
            // Create the cancellation source.
            cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            // Create the UI task scheduler from the current sychronization context.
            uiTaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

            // Create dataflow options
            var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions();
            options.CancellationToken = cancellationSource.Token;
            options.TaskScheduler = uiTaskScheduler;

            // Create dataflow nodes for the main thread and worker state machines
            mainQueue = new BufferBlock<StateMachineMessage>(options);
            workQueue = new BufferBlock<StateMachineMessage>(options);

            // Create the state machines for the worker and main thread
            mainMachine = new StateMachine("MainMach", mainQueue, richTextBox1);
            workerMachine = new StateMachine("WorkerMach", workQueue, richTextBox2);
        }

        public void StartStateMachines()
        {
            var mainTask = mainMachine.StartAsync();
            var workerTask = workerMachine.StartAsync();
        }

        ~Form1()
        {
            cancellationSource.Dispose();
        }

        private void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var request = new StateMachineMessage("REQUEST", "Hello World!", mainQueue);


            richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0}: {1}: {2}\n",
                              Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                              mainMachine.Name, request));

            workQueue.Post(request);
        }

        private async void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                workQueue.Complete();
                mainQueue.Complete();
                await Task.WhenAll(workQueue.Completion, mainQueue.Completion);
                richTextBox1.AppendText("All queues Completed\n");
                resetButton.Enabled = true;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void sendTenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
            {
                var request = new StateMachineMessage("REQUEST", "Hello World!", mainQueue);

                richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0}: {1}: {2}\n",
                                  Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                                  mainMachine.Name, request));

                workQueue.Post(request);
            }
        }

        private void resetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resetButton.Enabled = false;
            InitializeDataflow();
            StartStateMachines();
            richTextBox1.Clear();
            richTextBox2.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

One started each state machine loops on the BlockBuffer until cancelled. My question:

What is the correct async/await usage for the outermost StartStateMachines() method?

Silently ignoring the Tasks returned from each state machine start feels funny. I am relatively new to C# and am trying to use the async / await patterns where I would normally use a message queue and thread. I am also trying to be a bit modern and not use Invoke/BeginInvoke everywhere. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Sean

EDIT - I added the full state machine source and Program.cs here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataflowThread
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right now the code won't compile since `StateMachine` doesn't have a constructor that takes three parameters. It also seems odd each `StateMachineMachineMessage` has queue? At the very least you need to `await` the start tasks to know when they complete, but those buffers and every other dataflow block have a completion property for just that. If you could explain the code and the exact problem you have with it would help. There are much better ways of using dataflow, or another library that may be better suited to your application.

Comment: I added the full source code. See above. The intent is that each state machine can receive messages from any other state machine. The message contains a reference to the queue of the sending state machine. If a response is necessary the message provides necessary queue.

Comment: As I stated. I am new to C#. I am coming from an embedded background where you commonly create a number of message queues and tasks/state machines. Each state machine processes task asynchronously. The queues and tasks are persistent and do not exit after some number of operations. This is the model I am trying to emulate.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Dataflow is all about flowing data forward, even if it loops back on itself. But I think your going for something different here. [Have a look at this](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/Stateless30AStateMachineLibraryForNETCore.aspx), this library might better convey the ideas your trying to represent.

Comment: The Stateless library looks promising, thanks! I am still curious about how I should handle the fact that I have two Async method calls in StartStateMachines(). I want to let the state machine tasks process their respective message queues. I realize my description was not the best. Its late in the day and I am coming from a C /C++ background.

Comment: Fyi - My strategy for using BlockBuffer<> as a message queue came from Chapter 8 of the "Concurrency in C# Cookbook".

Comment: Excellent book. And to your other question, `StartStateMachines()` really needs to be `async` up to an event handler or something that can `await` an initialization `Task`. More about that from the same author is [Async Intialization](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html). FYI - a `BufferBlock<T>` is a great message queue but passing the reference around can quickly become tangled.

Comment: Thanks... have to re-think how to pass messages around.